# How do I calculate probabilities from a probability mass function?

Tags: statistics

If I have a PMF like so

[image]

Are the following correct?

1. $P(5 \leq x < 7) = 0.9$ $\quad (P(1) + P(3) + P(5))$
2. $P(1 < x \leq 5) = 0.5$ $\quad (P(3) + P(5))$
3. $P(5 < x \leq 7) = 0.1$ $\quad (P(7))$
4. $P(X = 5) = P(3 < x \leq 5) = 0.2$ $\quad (P(5))$
5. $P(1.3 < x < 6) = P(3 \leq x \leq 5) = 0.5$ $\quad(P(3) + P(5))$

Edit: Changed around some answers. I feel pretty confused about all this. Seems like there are a lot of what-ifs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a discrete random variable, so for any $A\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ we have $$P(x\in A)=\displaystyle\sum_{x_i\in A} P(x_i),$$ 
where $x_i\in \mathcal{R}(X)$.
From this formula directly follows answer to your question.

1. $P(5\leq x<7)=P(5)=0.2$
2. $P(1<x\leq 5)=P(3)+P(5)=0.5$
3. $P(5<x\leq 7)=P(7)=0.1$
4. $P(X=5)=0.2$
5. $P(1.3<x<6)=P(3)+P(5)=0.5$

Comment: Thanks that clears things up. I actually changed #2 though, so you might want to edit for others to see.